# How to know if a member has administration role / owner

Tags: discord, discord.js

So i want to make a discord.js code so if a message come from user who has admin role / he is owner i would return `console.log("The user has the role")` here's my current code:

```
module.exports = (client, message) => {
  if (message.member.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    console.log("he has")
  }
};
```

But it's says :
`cannot read property of undefined reading hasPermission`
i use handlers from notunderctrl : https://github.com/notunderctrl/discordjs-v14-series/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the [`permissionsFor`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor) method. Discord allows you to change a user's permissions for each channel, so you must check in the relevant channel. In your case, since you appear to be be using an `onMessage` handler, you can just use the channel related to the message. Some code would look like this:

```
module.exports = (client, message) => {
  if (message.channel.permissionsFor(message.member).has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
    console.log("he has")
  }
};
```